# How can i make a SQL query from actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can i make a SQL query from actionscript? and render all the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call a serverside script (for example php) and then retrieve the output of that script

```
private var _loader:URLLoader;
private var _request:URLRequest;

private function loadData():void {
    _loader = new URLLoader();
    _request = new URLRequest("path/to/your/phpscript");
    _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFailedToLoad);
    _loader.load(_request);
}
private function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
    trace("onLoadData",e.target.data);
}
private function onDataFailedToLoad(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("onDataFailedToLoad:",e.text);
}
```

an example php script:

```
<?php

    // defining main variables
    $dbHost = "localhost";
    $dbUser = "root";
    $dbPass = "";
    $dbName = "test";
    $dbTable = "data";

    // connecting and selecting database
    @mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error());
    @mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

    // getting data
    $data = "";
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbTable." ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
        $data .= "nname=".$row->name.", ";
        $data .= "city=".$row->city;
    }
    echo $data;

?>
```

For a better workflow, I suggest looking into AMF...

[Here's a tutorial on AMF](http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/helloAS3/)

Answer (score 3):

There's no real equivalent to JDBC or ODBC for working in Flex that I'm aware of.  Most likely this just wasn't really explored as something to attempt to deliver since Flex/Flash is generally client side and the DB is generally server side (shared).  Generally speaking you'd use Java, PHP, C#, ASP .NET, Python, C++, or some other server side program to establish the connection to a DB and run queries.  The closest thing to what your question is asking that I've seen is this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html but only applies to AIR and not for remote SQL connections.  I'm not entirely sure how much work is involved in writing up a JDBC like interface/implementation to connect to any given DB I suppose in part it depends on how well documented the DBMS is... either way my guess is it'd be a ton of work.

**EDIT**

Okay so actually eating my words to some degree, apparently it is somewhat feasible: http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/browse_thread/thread/d89bb5120fad7369?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

You -really- don't want to do SQL query connections from Flex, especially if the application is distributed to users. Flash/Flex applications can be easily decompiled into readable source code, and if you're SQL connection string is in the source, you're going to have all kinds of security problems. It's a significantly better idea to have Flex use a restful web API to server-side languages like PHP, Python, Perl, or Node to do the SQL data processing for you.

Even if your application is internal, it's still a better concept "on paper" to keep Flex away from directly manipulating the database.